# Setting Actionbar title with a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My app has a `ListView` on startup.  The user can either manually select an item in the `ListView` to go to a details screen or swipe using a `ViewPager` between the different details screens.  The `ViewPager's` fragments are setup like this:

```
Listing
Detail 1
Detail 2
Detail 3
Detail 4
...
```

It's my understanding, when the Listing fragment is loaded, the `ViewPager` will execute Detail 1's code, for performance.  The same when Detail 1 is loaded, Detail 2's code will execute.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm setting the title of each detail fragment in `onActivityCreated`, however, when the Listing fragment is loaded, it is displaying Detail 1's title.  So I moved the code to `onPageSelected` of the `ViewPager`, which works if the user is swiping, but if the user manually selects an item in the `ListView` the title is never set.

I'm not sure if there is an event that is only fired when a user manually selects an item in the `ListView` and not when they are swiping or if I need to rethink my apps' setup.  For example, instead of using this code in the Listing fragment's `onListItemClick` event:

```
final Intent listing = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Details.class);
startActivity(listing);
```

I need to somehow use the `ViewPager`.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);  
mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setSaveEnabled(false);
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {      
        String title = GetTitle(position);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);                  
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixel) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to override the method [`getPageTitle(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageTitle%28int%29) in your `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` class. The documentation states:

> This method may be called by the ViewPager to obtain a title string to
>   describe the specified page. This method may return null indicating no
>   title for this page. The default implementation returns null.

So rather than returning `null`, make sure you return the actual page title. You get passed in the position/index of the page the title is requested for, so a simple switch-case statement should suffice. Alternatively, you could set up an interface for your pages and query the relevant page for its title.

Comment: I actually got it working by using an event callback in the details fragment, instead of starting a new activity, when clicking on an item in the `ListView` and keeping the title update code in `onPageSelected`